# simple C/C++ question

Tags: c++, c, char

I do that:

```
char asa[2];
char c = '2';
asa[0] = c;
asa[1] = '\0';
printf("%s", asa);
```

is it right in terms of code validation?

If I debug the asa values aren't updated untill the printf is called...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What do you mean by "is it right?"  What are you trying to do?  It's hard to know what's "right" without also knowing what's "wrong."

Comment: Welcome okami. Your code is correct. Are you using a visual debugger to inspect the values of asa?

Comment: did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: On all debuggers I know, the `(->)` pointer in the source code pointing at the current line shows you what will be executed *next*. So if it points at `(->) printf("%s", asa);` that means the `printf` function will be called next.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct.

And my answer needs to be at least this long.

Comment: I prefer using ***** FILLER ****** ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, yes. As for why your values aren't being updated it probably has to do with your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is correct.

As for the debugging thing are you sure that this is the case? Try checking the value of asa[0] when the debugger is on the asa[1] = '\0'; line. The value should update immediately. If not its likely an issue with the debugger and not your code.